# Creating AWS SES SMTP credentials using IAM Role

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-ses

I am trying to use an IAM Role that I have attached to an EC2 instance to generate a set of AWS SES SMTP credentials. However, after using the script given by Amazon to generate the SMTP Password from the Secret_Key of the IAM Role, and using the Access_Key_ID of the IAM Role, when trying to send an email via django.core.mail, I get error `(535, b'Authentication Credentials Invalid')`.

This is how I am sending the email:

```
#django.core.mail
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = credentials.access_key
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = SMTP_PASSWORD

send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

And how am I generating the password:

```
session = boto3.session.Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials().get_frozen_credentials()
region = requests.get('http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document').json()['region']
SMTP_PASSWORD = smtp_credentials_generate.calculate_key(secret_access_key=credentials.secret_key, region=region)
```

The SMTP Password generate script is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html.

Through some research, I found these links that say you cannot use an IAM Role to use generate SMTP credentials:

https://serverfault.com/questions/584789/is-it-possible-to-send-email-via-the-amazon-ses-smtp-service-with-a-iam-role-acc
https://hector.dev/2015/01/17/sending-e-mail-via-amazon-ses-over-smtp-with-iam-roles.html

However, Amazons official QA says that it is possible:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ses-create-smtp-credentials/

> Important: The IAM user **or role** that you use to create the SMTP credentials...

So is it possible or not? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The smtp credentials can only be generated using the secret key of the IAM user, it can’t be generated using a temporary password, to use assume role and temporary credentials, you need to make api calls sendrawemail etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html

> Don't use temporary AWS credentials to derive SMTP credentials. The Amazon SES SMTP interface doesn't support SMTP credentials that have been generated from temporary security credentials.

Regarding the Amazon official QA that you referenced, it's saying that you can use the role to create SMTP credentials **in the web console**.